# "Member for 0 months" in leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

On the per site leaderboards of Winter Bash (e.g. [Meta leaderboard](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com)) it displays the "member for" information. Two problems:

1. If user is member for exactly X years it displays "member for X years, 0 months":

   > [image]

   Should be "member for 3 years" by all means.
2. If user is member for less than a month, it's even worse:

   > [image]

   Should probably be "member for less than a month".

Comment: @AustinHenley it's rare to find anyone here who is *not* pedantic! :-)

Comment: If this is status by-design, it's a clear case of Bad Design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relative time display is fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 7):

It's technically correct... and we all know what kind of correct that is.

Comment: "We kept it gray..."