# Site age in Stack Exchange sites list showing "1y0m"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

In the [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) sites active for exactly whole year(s) are showing something like:

> > [image]

This feels wrong, better be just "1y".

Worth to mention that [similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159740/152859) was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159755/152859) in the Winterbash recently. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now show "2y" and "1y" instead of "2y0m" and "1y0m" on the sites list page.

Looking at it again, I'm not quite sure I like it more this way (aesthetically), so I'm curious to know what everyone else thinks.

Comment: Thanks! Well, +11/-2 not much attention but also not much objection. Dunno, "0m" just feels wrong.